# Python Flask print key

Tags: python, flask

How can I print my dictionary dinamically with the flask?

```
 @app.route("/")    
 def hello():    


  templateData = {    

  'canzone': vasco rossi,    
  'destinazione': /home/vasco.mp3    

  }    
  return render_template('main.html', **templateData)
```

My dictionary is composed:

```
  print dizionario:
  vascorossi:/home/vasco.mp3
  eros:/home/canzone.mp3
  etc...
```

And I would like it could be in html:

index.html:

```
  vascorossi - albachiara
  eros - canzone
  all the keys and value contents
```

Comment: did you know about jinja templating ?

Comment: Do you want to iterate over the keys of your dictionary in your template? Because you can do that in jinja templates. You need to pass a dictionary as one of the template variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python update this function to below version.

```
@app.route("/")    
def hello():    
    templateData = {     
        'canzone': vasco rossi,    
        'destinazione': /home/vasco.mp3    
    }
    updated_dict = {}
    for key in templateData.keys():
        updated_dict[key.decode('utf-8')] = templateData[key.decode('utf-8')].key.decode('utf-8')
    return render_template('main.html', templateData=updated_dict)
```

And in main.html add below piece of script to display key value pairs on your html page.

**main.html**

```
...
{% for key in templateData.keys() %}
  {{ key }} <br>
  {{ templateData[key] }}
{% endfor %}
...
```

Comment: yes ! this is right but when i write:
     @app.route("/")
     def hello():

      templateData = {
        'canali':dict.keys(),
        'destinazione':dict.values()
     }
      return render_template('main.html', templateData=templateData)


     if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
they print all in the dictionary and how i can print separately?
templateData[key]
templateData[value]
templateData[Key]
templateData[Value]?

Comment: Can you please update your question, And add a formatted output that you want ?

Comment: @fabriziobianchi check, I have solved unicode error problem

Comment: Yes! Great!  have converted all lines in dictionary in unicode 8.
And now, how i can visualize the destination of dictionary as href link?

Comment: Yes, you can convert test into href link by editing main.html e.g <a href="#">{{ templateData[key] }}</a>

Comment: Perfect well done! and ,   now i read this in each link:  [u'
How i can remove from each lines?